# ctrl+click in xhtml file don't work with Spring @Component annotation

Tags: eclipse, spring, jsf

I have a problem with linking with ctrl+click from xhtml file to class methods when use Spring @Component. Everything works fine when I switch it to @ManagedBean. What could be the problem?

Example:

```
<h:inputText id="name" value="#{mainController.name}" />
```

doesn't works with:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Component
@Scope("session")
public class MainController implements Serializable{

private String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

but works with:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class MainController implements Serializable{

private String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

I already have:

```
<application>
    <el-resolver>
        org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver
    </el-resolver>
</application>
```

in my faces-config.xml file.
I use Auto scan in applicationContext.xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.integra" />
```

I totally wants to use Spring beans. Thank you!

Comment: Spring is not part of standard Java EE. It's a 3rd party framework. It's therefore not by default recognized by standard Eclipse for Java EE. It'd make sense to look for a 3rd party Eclipse plugin as well ...

Comment: Are you using the Spring Tools Suite?